# Riot JS unmount all tags in a page and then mount only one tag is not working

Tags: riot.js

I am using Riot JS and in my index.html, I have 3 custom tags - header, login-panel and candidates-panel inside my body. In my main app.js, in the callback function of $(document).ready, I execute the current route and also register a route change handler function. In my switchView, I unmount all custom tags and then try to mount only the tag pertaining to the current view being switched. Here is my code. If I do unmount, then nothing is displayed on the page

index.html

```
<body>
    <header label="Hire Zen" icon="img/user-8-32.png"></header>
    <login-panel class="viewTag" id="loginView"></login-panel>

    <candidates-panel id="candidatesView" class="viewTag"></candidates-panel>
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
function switchView(view) {
    if(!view || view === '') {
        view = 'login'
    }
    //unmount all other panels and mount only the panel that is required
    //TODO: unmount all view panels and mounting only required panel is not working
    //riot.unmount('.viewTag')
    riot.mount(view+'-panel')
    $('.viewTag').hide()
    $(view+'-panel').show()
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    RiotControl.addStore(new AuthStore())
    RiotControl.addStore(new CandidatesStore())
    riot.mount('header')
    //register route change handler
    riot.route(function (collection, id, action) {
        switchView(collection)
    })
    riot.route.exec(function (collection, id, action) {
        switchView(collection)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for riot.js v2.1.0:

The function

```
riot.unmount(...)
```

is not available as far as I know. However, you can unmount saved tags.

```
mytag.unmount(true)
```

[Source](https://muut.com/riotjs/api/#tag-unmount)

The trick is to remember the mounted tags to be able to unmount them later:

```
var viewTag = riot.mount(document.getElementById('viewTag'))
viewTag.unmount(true)
```

You can store all those view tags in an object and loop them to unmount all and mount only the active one.

[Source](https://muut.com/riotjs/api/#mount-dom)

Answer (score 1):

Answer for 2.3.18

Based on the previous answer and [this tutorial](http://streamdata.io/blog/exploring-riot-js-part4/) I have created following concept:

```
app.currentPage = null;

var goTo = function(page){
  if (app.currentPage) {
    app.currentPage.unmount(true); //unmount and keep parent tag
  }
  app.currentPage = riot.mount(page)[0]; //remember current page
};

riot.route(function() {
  console.info("this page is not defined");
  //do nothing (alternatively go to 404 page or home)
});

riot.route('/inventory', function(){
  goTo('inventory');
});

riot.route('/options', function() {
  goTo('options');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `riot.util.tags.unmountAll(tags)`

How to achieve the goal?

**index.html**

```
var tags = [];
```

**some.tag.html**

```
var some = this;
tags.push(some);
```

**unmountAllTags.js**

```
riot.util.tags.unmountAll(tags);
```